# How to retrieve data and show depend on dropdownlist using javascript and codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ajaxq

I've store this below information in database and I want to show for my visitor after they selected on each option in drop down by using ajax in jqueryor or javascript in Codeigniter. But I don't know how to do.

```
    <div class="desp">Description for deporset</div>
    <div class="pre">Description for prepayment</div>
    <div calss=""month">Description for monthly fee</div>
    <div class="instal">Description for installation fee</div>
```

This is drop down using for user to select it and show above information.

```
<select name="" class="form-control" placeholder="typee">
       <option value="deporsit">deporsit</option>
       <option value="preparement">preparement</option>
       <option value="monthly fee">monthly fee</option>
       <option value="instalation fee">instalation fee</option>
</select>
```

Please give me some idea or any tutorial about this please.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following article will help you:

http://mikeheavers.com/main/code-item/dynamic_dependent_dropdown_filtering_with_codeigniter_and_jquery